# Calling a function within an object property from another property

Tags: jquery, html

In my jQuery code I tried to call an object's `fullName()` method inside another method named `init()`. `fullName()` binds to the object itself so it is working if I try to `alert(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);` or try to bind it inside another `<p id="view"></p>`.

However, it isn't working if i try `this.html(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);`. Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var person = {
    firstName: "my",
    lastName: "name",
    init: function() {
      this.fullName();
    },
    fullName: function() {
      $('p#show').click(function() {
        // alert(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
        // $('p#view').html(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
        this.html(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  };
  
  person.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="show">Click me</p>
<p id="view"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is due to scope. You're expecting `this` to refer to both the `#show` element selected through jQuery *and* the `person` object. Clearly it can't be both.

Given your use of `bind()`, `this` within the handler function will refer to the `person` object, but that prevents access to jQuery's `html()` method from `this`, and is the reason for the `this.html is not a function` error you receive.

To fix the problem create a variable within scope of the `fillName` function and save the reference to `person` there. Then use that inside the jQuery event handler function, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var person = {
    firstName: "my",
    lastName: "name",
    init: function() {
      this.fullName();
    },
    fullName: function() {
      var _person = this;
      $('p#show').click(function() {
        $(this).html(_person.firstName + " " + _person.lastName);
      });
    }
  };
  
  person.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="show">Click me</p>
<p id="view"></p>
```